# SELECT FROM DB_TABLE with left join where column from joined table

Tags: abap, opensql

I want to create a select that left joins multiple tables.

In the following code, I need to select only lines of table `EKPO` where column `EBELN` = variable `lv_ebeln`. But as soon as I add this condition to the `WHERE`, I get this syntax error:

> The elements in the "SELECT LIST" list must be separated using commas.

So, is there a way to add this condition?

```
DATA: BEGIN OF wa_itab,
        gjahr TYPE rseg-gjahr,
        ebelp TYPE ekpo-ebelp,
      END OF wa_itab,
      itab     LIKE TABLE OF wa_itab,
      lv_belnr TYPE rseg-belnr,
      lv_ebeln TYPE ekpo-ebeln.

SELECT rseg~gjahr ekpo~ebelp FROM rseg
  LEFT JOIN ekpo ON rseg~ebeln = ekpo~ebeln AND rseg~ebelp = ekpo~ebelp
  INTO (wa_itab-gjahr, wa_itab-ebelp )
  WHERE rseg~belnr = lv_belnr 
    AND ekpo~ebeln = lv_ebeln. " <=== SYNTAX ERROR because of this line

  ...
  " some other code
  ...

  APPEND wa_itab TO itab.
ENDSELECT.
```

Comment: I edited the message so that the code is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I removed the part about the performance because it's a different question. Feel free to ask it separately.

Comment: From the `WHERE` condition it is clear that what you need is an `INNER JOIN` and not `LEFT (OUTER) JOIN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax error message is misleading, the commas are not required, because the problem is not related to the [OpenSQL strict mode](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenopensql_strict_modes.htm).

The true error is that in a left outer join, the condition on the right table `EKPO` is not accepted in the `WHERE` because if the join result has some lines only from the left table `RSEG`, the columns from the right table `EKPO` will have the value `null` and thus the conditions based on the right table columns are false and the lines are not selected, making the left outer join behave like an inner join.

- Either you use an inner join with the condition in the `WHERE` (what you don't want).
- Or you keep the left outer join and you move the condition to the `ON` join condition as below.

Code:

```
SELECT rseg~gjahr ekpo~ebelp FROM rseg
  LEFT JOIN ekpo ON rseg~ebeln = ekpo~ebeln 
                AND rseg~ebelp = ekpo~ebelp
                AND ekpo~ebeln = lv_ebeln " <=== move it here
  INTO (wa_itab-gjahr, wa_itab-ebelp )
  WHERE rseg~belnr = lv_belnr.
```

---

PS: I don't find a reference in the ABAP documentation that explains it officially, except there is this [close example](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapselect_join.htm):

```
SELECT s~carrid, s~carrname 
   FROM scarr AS s 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN spfli AS p ON s~carrid   =  p~carrid 
                              AND p~cityfrom = @cityfr  " <=== not in the WHERE
   WHERE p~connid IS NULL 
   ORDER BY s~carrid, s~carrname 
   INTO TABLE @DATA(itab).
```

Comment: You do not find it in the ABAP documentation because these are SQL basics.